# Add hook on uparrow symbol

Tags: symbols

I want to make a hook on the uparrow in the following part, but could not find any command to do so.

```
\begin{array}\
0 \to C_3 \hookrightarrow SL_3 (\mathbb{C}) \twoheadrightarrow PSL_3(\mathbb{C})\to 0\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \uparrow \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \uparrow\\
0 \to K \hookrightarrow \mathcal{V} \twoheadrightarrow A_6 \to 0 \\
\end{array}
```

EDIT: More precisely, I want to create three hooked uparrows just below $C_3, SL_3 (\mathbb{C}), PSL_3(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: You should have a look at [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://goo.gl/NjJCc)

Comment: this appears to be an attempt to produce a commutative diagram.  it's recommended to use a package for this.  `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usepackage{xy}` (also known as xy-pic) are the packages most often suggested; both provide many different arrow shapes, including the one you are looking for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, please see the edit now!

Comment: actually, it was clear to me what's wanted, without the edit.  egreg has gone ahead and produced the diagram using `tikz`, which is really the better way to do these. it would be to your benefit to become familiar with `tikz` -- it's useful for lots more than just commutative diagrams.  if you're using an installation based on tex live, `texdoc tikz` will pull up the manual in pdf form.  it's long, but very interesting reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it would be possible to get the arrow you want, it's better to use a dedicated package for drawing these diagrams:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]
0 \arrow[r] &
  C_{3} \arrow[r,hook] &
  \mathit{SL}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[r,two heads] &
  \mathit{PSL}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[r] & 0
\\
0 \arrow[r] &
  K \arrow[r,hook] &
  \mathcal{V} \arrow[r,two heads] \arrow[u,hook] &
  A_{6} \arrow[r] \arrow[u,hook] & 0
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that when `tikzcd` is used in `beamer` the `&` must be masked just like it happens for all TikZ related constructions that use `&`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
0 \arrow[r] \&
  C_{3} \arrow[r,hook] \&
  \mathit{SL}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[r,two heads] \&
  \mathit{PSL}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[r] \& 0
\\
0 \arrow[r] \&
  K \arrow[r,hook] \arrow[u,hook] \&
  \mathcal{V} \arrow[r,two heads] \arrow[u,hook] \&
  A_{6} \arrow[r] \arrow[u,hook] \& 0
\end{tikzcd}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The alternative is to use `&` without `ampersand replacement` but the `frame` must be declared `fragile` (this slows down LaTeX, though):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow[r] &
  C_{3} \arrow[r,hook] &
  \mathit{SL}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[r,two heads] &
  \mathit{PSL}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[r] & 0
\\
0 \arrow[r] &
  K \arrow[r,hook] \arrow[u,hook] &
  \mathcal{V} \arrow[r,two heads] \arrow[u,hook] &
  A_{6} \arrow[r] \arrow[u,hook] & 0
\end{tikzcd}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @monomorphic Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Hi, how can I do similar thing in \documentclass{beamer}?

Comment: @monomorphic Where's the problem? This should work as is also in `beamer`.

Comment: sorry, it does not work.

Comment: @monomorphic I added the workarounds.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to use `tikzcd` in `\documentclass{memoir}`. How can I produce the diagrams like the one above?

Comment: @monomorphic It should work independently of the document class. What error do you get? Of course you shouldn't use `frame`, which is just for `beamer`.

Comment: The error I get is something like: `No shape named tikz@f@1-2 is known`. I haven't used `frame`.

Comment: @monomorphic That means you have an arrow pointing to a non existent target. Say ``X\arrow[rr] &Y\\`` when there's no position two places on the right.

Comment: I have used your very first code, from your answer.

Comment: @monomorphic It compiles fine for me. Open a new question with a MWE showing the error.

Comment: I am surprised that there is no error regarding `tikz` but still it does not compile for me. I am not sure what is this.

Comment: Hi, I have asked a [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220413/how-to-write-use-tikz-in-documentclassmemoir-properly).