# How to use tikz with memoir

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, memoir

I have used the following code after suggestion from an [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213460/add-hook-on-uparrow-symbol).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]
0 \arrow[r] &
  C_{3} \arrow[r,hook] &
  \mathit{SL}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[r,two heads] &
  \mathit{PSL}_{3}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[r] & 0
\\
0 \arrow[r] &
  K \arrow[r,hook] &
  \mathcal{V} \arrow[r,two heads] \arrow[u,hook] &
  A_{6} \arrow[r] \arrow[u,hook] & 0
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

But this does not work at all; the commutative diagrams just don't display. More surprisingly, I don't get any error about this. But above code works perfectly for `\documentclass{article}`. What can I do to make this work on `\documentclass{memoir}`?

**Added:** A list of packages used is given here:

`memoir.cls    2013/05/30 v3.7b configurable book, report, article document cl
ass
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
   mem11.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 11pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
microtype-pdftex.def    2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   dvips.def    2014/04/23 v3.0j Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 tikz-cd.sty    2014/10/26 v0.9d Commutative diagrams with tikz
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty

 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty

 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
   amscd.sty    1999/11/29 v2.0
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
memhfixc.sty    2013/05/30 v1.17 nameref/hyperref package fixes for memoir clas
s
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   t1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
  mt-ptm.cfg    2006/04/20 v1.7 microtype config. file: Times (RS)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
  output.out
  output.out
   t1phv.fd    2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (
RS)
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
  mt-msa.cfg    2006/02/04 v1.1 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (a) (RS)
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
  mt-msb.cfg    2005/06/01 v1.0 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (b) (RS)
  omsptm.fd

  output.bbl`

Comment: Check your packages. Something must be old.  Perhaps a local version? This compiles fine for me (TL 2014).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. How can I check?

Comment: Put `\listfiles` as the first line of your document and towards the end of the log file you will see the complete list of packages loaded and their version numbers.  Copy that list and add it to your question. Also, what TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Added. But I am not sure if that's what you meant!

Comment: That's not the list from your minimal document!  Just post that list, not the one from your actual document. :)

Comment: Can you also delete the `.aux` file and compile fresh? Not seeing without an error is strange and maybe you are seeing the old result.

Comment: @AlanMunn Could you tell me what a list typically looks like. I don't seem to understand what list I need to look for.

Comment: The list you posted is the right kind of list, but you need to post the list based on adding `\listfiles` to the minimal document (i.e. the exact one in your question), compiling that (after deleting the .aux files first) and then looking at the log file of *that* compilation.  You'll get a similar list but it will be a lot smaller.

Comment: I see what you mean. It works perfectly well when I am just considering the minimal document. But does not work when above code between `\begin{} ... \end` is inside my main file. How can I resolve this? I should have asked the question differently.

Comment: Start with a copy of your main document and keep taking stuff out until taking anything else out eliminates the error. Then post that code as your minimal example. We need to see code which produces the error - otherwise all we can do is say that something else must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: Everything works now. I just commented the `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`. Before doing this, it wasn't working. But I don't understand the error though.

Comment: @monomorphic The `dvips` option shouldn't be passed to `graphicx` (you don't need to comment out that package, just remove the option.) It assumes you are using a different way of compiling and not using `pdflatex` (which is what you are using.)